# virtual host access from another computer

Tags: virtualhost, wampserver, wamp3

I am working in a php project using wamp. I have these wamp installed in my public server, so till now when I hit 204.XXX.XX.XX/projectname I could access from any computer inside my university. Now I dont want to display this localhost main screen so I tried virtual host configuration.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file

```
I added 
204.XXX.XX.XX   api.local   #api
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName api.local
  ServerAlias api.local
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/api"
  <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/api/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have already enabled the virtual host.

Now from other computer I could not access this api.local project. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

THe reason is that the other computer does not know where to find `api.local`. The browser will look for that domain name in the DNS Server that is registered to be used on the OTHER PC and obviously not find it.

So the other PC needs to know the ip address to go to when you enter `api.local`. You can do this in a number of ways.

If your Uni techs will allow you to add this domain name to their DNS Server this is the best way.

But if they wont allow this, then you will have to edit the HOSTS file on the OTHER PC like this

```
204.xxx.xxx.xxx api.local
```

Now this one PC will know where to find your site. However the HOSTS file is normally well protected and you would need Administrator access to change it, which you admins may not allow.

Another way would be to make the site available on a different port, then you can use the WAMPServer PC ip address and a port number to get to your site like this

```
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  ServerName api.local
  ServerAlias api.local
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/api"
  <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/api/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now use `204.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000` as the site address and you should get to your site

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried second method. But I am not being able to access the folder.

Comment: Ahh yes, the hosts file is normally protected from casual access. Looks like method 3 is your only option

Comment: what is method 3

Comment: Using another port number